# Imposing axis sizes in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I want to put two plots on the same pdf page.
The first plot needs an aspect ratio of 1.

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- 1:5
t <- 1:5
pdf("test.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x,y,asp=1)
plot(z,t)
dev.off()
```

I end up with the following:
[image]

Let's say negative values have no meaning in the context of the first plot. How can I do to get a square plot instead of this horizontally spread rectangle ?

I tried specifying `xlim=c(0, 6)` and `ylim=c(0, 6)`, but the plot is still a long rectangle with empty spaces on both sides of the points. Besides, I may not know in advance what the highest values are.

Ideally, I would like to be able to say: For the first plot, start the axes at 0, use the same length for both axes, fit the first plot in the first half of an A4 page, and the second plot in the second half of the same page.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tact to force square plotting regions is to add pty="s" to the `par` function:

```
pdf("temp.pdf", height=11, width=8.5)
par(mfrow=c(2,1), pty="s")
plot(x,y,asp=1, xlim=c(0, 6))
plot(z,t, xlim=c(0, 6))
dev.off()
```

From the help file, `?par`, the pty argument takes

> A character specifying the type of plot region to be used; "s" generates a square plotting region and "m" generates the maximal plotting region.

Comment: Using `pty="s"` indeed gives me square plots, but for some reason, a lot of margin is left around them on the page (only one third of the page width is used). Shouldn't the plot automatically use more space ? Is there a way to set a given axis' size?

Comment: @bli try `pdf("temp.pdf", height=11, width=11/2)` or something

Comment: @rawr Thanks, this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change pdf's width and height like this:

```
pdf("test.pdf",width=2.height=5)
```

and then

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x,y)#remove asp=1
plot(z,t)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Why remove `asp=1`? I want x and y to be represented on the same scale.

Comment: Sorry,I don't know why it is.But as in your plot,if use asp=1,the x limits from -4 to 10;else remove it,the x limits from 1 to 5.Also you can use xlim=c(1,5)

Comment: Maybe you can use RStudio to help you change plots' size .It is useful.